# SQL query to get daily acquisitions

Tags: sql

I have a sales table:

```
date, user_id, product
```

there are 26 products(a-z), and those users who have purchased both 'a' and 'b' product are classified as acquired customers.

What I want is the daily level count of acquired customers as a SQL query
Say for eg, A user 'X' bought product 'a' on 1st apr, and bought product 'b' on 20th apr then he will be deemed as acquired on 20th apr.

Need a SQL query for this

Sample data:

```
date    user_id Product sale
01-04-2019  123 a   200
01-04-2019  234 b   300
01-04-2019  345 a   200
02-04-2019  123 b   300
03-04-2019  234 b   300
04-04-2019  555 g   400
05-04-2019  666 a   200
05-04-2019  666 b   300
```

Desired Output from sql query:

```
date    ac-quired_users
01-04-2019  0
02-04-2019  1
03-04-2019  0
04-04-2019  0
05-04-2019  1
```

obviously there will be a lot more data

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and why it is not working.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this.  First, get the "start" date for each user:

```
select userid, min(date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when product = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid order by date) as cnt_a,
             sum(case when product = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid order by date) as cnt_b
      from t
     ) t
from t
group by userid;
```

Then aggregate this:

```
select date, count(*)
from (select userid, min(date)
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when product = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid order by date) as cnt_a,
                   sum(case when product = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid order by date) as cnt_b
            from t
           ) t
      from t
      group by userid
     ) u
group by date
order by date;
```